# Select row with value older than 60 seconds

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select all rows where the value of the **updated_on** field is older than 60 seconds.

I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM processes WHERE updated_on < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 SECOND)
```

However, i get an empty result.

For example, there is a row which has "2014-04-15 10:43:22" as the **updated_on** value (a timestamp field).

What is wrong?

Comment: it shouldn't be `updated_on >` ?

Comment: @Tuga how is that? If the row is older, then it's timestamp is supposed to have a lower value than `NOW()`. It is like: you are older than me, so `your birthyear < my birthyear`.

Comment: Yeah that was exactly what i was thinking.

Comment: My idea is that you should check the time of your server. `SELECT NOW()`, it might have a wrong timezone or something.

Comment: @Michael: What is the correct data type of `updated_on`?

Comment: @Ravinder it is a `timestamp`, he specified in the question.

Comment: @Jari: Yes. I read that. But due to the issue, I asked if it was *correct*. I should also have asked as *what time is it `now()` on db*?

Comment: @Jari, you are right. The server returns "2014-04-15 05:35:53". But i am a bit confused. I have set the extra for the specic field to "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP". Why is it inserting the wrong timestamp then?

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is still related to the server time. You might find a proper answer here on how to set date in mysql. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-timezone-of-mysql Also, if those rows are important to you, just calculate the time difference between real timezone and the wrong timezone, and perform timeshift on all rows using `UPDATE`

Comment: WHat you mean with "related to the server time"? Are CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and now() using different sources for the timezone? Sadly i can't modify the timezone settings.

Comment: Okay i found the problem. I had the wrong timezone at the PHP settings. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

you should must mention `greater than`

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM processes WHERE updated_on > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 SECOND);
```

---

try this: **update:1**

```
SELECT * FROM processes WHERE updated_on < unix_timestamp(now() - interval 60 second);
```

Comment: Well, then it also returns rows which are not older than 60 seconds. e.g. it returns a row with that value in the updated_on field "2014-04-17 10:43:22". No idea why.

Comment: Also take a look at the comments from above.

Comment: Thanks, but does not work. The exact same result that i get with my query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `processes` where TIMESTAMPDIFF( SECOND , updated_on, NOW()) < 60
```